# How to TurnOn FileVault for (Macintosh HD - Data) while it is already On for (Macintosh HD)

Tags: disk-utility, encryption, filevault, apfs, secure-erase

I saw on the Apple documents on their website ( Here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650 ) that Macintosh HD is read-only volume called maybe "startup disk" for system files and user data goes to Macintosh HD - Data,

But I can't find that volume in my macbook or in Filevault there is no option coming to turn FileVault On For "Macintosh HD - Data", it only says there "Filevault is turned on for the disk Macintosh HD" does it mean that the user data is still unencrypted!, and it was On already by default, I didn't turned it On.

But I want to encrypt the user data wherever it is by FileVault in order to securely erase it from the Macbook in future whenever needed.

Please tell me how to do it or where to find that volume or explain to me if the user data is also on the "Macintosh HD" only but in the Disk Utility there is an another Volume called only "Data" other than the "Macintosh HD"

I am confused why is it not showing in the FileVault that means it is not encrypted and it is where the user data is going?

can this happen that it is already encrypted and I can stop worrying or what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this mean that your data is already encrypted. There's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Then why there are two volumes in the Disk Utility, and only one of them that is "Macintosh HD" is said to be secured in the Filevault ,that can mean that it is not encrypted and that is where user data is going..please explain to me.

Comment: No, that’s not how it works. Your data is secure - you have nothing to worry about. The other volume is a system volume containing a copy of macOS in principle identical to every other Mac running the same system version. It doesn’t contain any user data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer so much @jksoegaard but i have edited the question making things more clear please look at that and then explain me.

Comment: The edit doesn’t change anything. Your data is encrypted. Try running “diskutil list” in the Terminal - perhaps that puts your mind at ease.